# Laravel Homestead Benefits of using it

Tags: laravel

What are the advantages of using Laravel Homestead over the default one?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/6-reasons-move-laravel-homestead/
:)

Comment: What "default one"?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. There are so many advantages of using Laravel Homestead.

And most of these benefits come when you use it for simulating how your site would look on production side. It gets you to know the important errors that you might come across while publishing this site on a public server.

I guess you should use it if you are developing with Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

I'll list down few advantages of using Laravel Homestead:

1. **It’s Fast and Easy to Set Up**
   Setting Homestead up is a piece of cake. Following the instructions on the documentation page, all you need to do is add the homestead box to your Vagrant (if you don’t have it yet) and clone the repo.
2. **Easy to add sites**
   Due to the simplicity of the configuration file one can tweak when fine tuning Homestead, adding new sites (vhosts) is a breeze – you don’t even have to deal with individual vhost configurations in nginx files.
3. **It Works**
   Unlike the other popular solutions out there for simplifying Vagrantfile setups, Homestead seldom fails to boot, and if it does, it’s fixed within minutes.
4. **Otwell Approved**
   Homestead being official, as in, made by Taylor Otwell, the father of Laravel, means it’s automatically assumed to hold to certain standards.
5. **Ports**
   Homestead opens certain important ports by default which make maintaining and managing your database and other installed software on the VM from the host machine a breeze.